# "I don't mind him" in the context

Tags: meaning

I have learned the cast of the leading role in one movie. The actor is not personally my favourite and I can imagine the better choice but on the other hand there many other actors that I dislike much more. I want to express that with all my reservations I bear this actor and accept his cast. Is it possible to say "I don't mind him in this role" in that context? The statement should be a positive connotation.

Comment: How colloquial or formal is your statement supposed to be?

Answer (score 2):

I would say "I don't mind" is more neutral than positive, it can have the meaning of indifference as in "It doesn't matter Brad Pitt is in the role". "I don't mind Brad Pitt in that role" also has the connotation that you have an opinion of the role, as opposed to the actor, and that someone else might be better, but at least Brad Pitt doesn't detract from the role.

Just to add: **I don't mind** usually means the solution is adequate, where as **I don't mind one bit** is very positive.

Answer (score 2):

"I don't mind him" literally means that you have an absence of negative feeling.  This is hardly a ringing endorsement.

Answer (score 1):

'I don't mind', although positive, could be seen as not very positive. If you were to say 'I don't mind Brad Pitt in that role' you would be saying that you didn't 'love' Brad Pitt in that role, but would not quite be saying that you 'did not' like him in that role. It would usually be used in a context like "I didn't mind Brad Pitt in that role, but I loved him in x'.

Short version = 'I don't mind' would be seen as only a little positive, but not negative. (First time I've answered a question in this community, so be gentle!)

Comment: Welcome aboard! :-)

Comment: Thankyou :) Very new to this and hope that I can be helpful!

Comment: Hoping and attempting are the important things here, imo.  Do your best, and the voting system will tell you where you go successful, and where you are unsuccessful!